# model.summary() when call divides its inputs prints multiple, can't print output shape

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, subclassing

I am trying to build a model in TF2 with subclassing API, where self.call() function I am reconstructing the input image and therefore passing the input image but also the target solution of it.

I am doing this because in my loss function, I want my architecture to keep the information of the initial image (the original architecture does not use a ReLu but a vector encoding all the information with several dimensions). Therefore, I have generated a custom train loop that basically uses the reconstructed image in the custom loss_function.

I can get it to work with a single input to the call function. But if I have two input tensors: input_tensor = [tensor_X, tensor_Y].

Code sample that works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class subclass(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(28, 3, strides=1)
        self.pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))

        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu')
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=784, activation='relu')

    def model(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

    def call(self, inputs):
        # x, y = inputs
        x = inputs
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        v = tf.nn.relu(x)

        rec = self.dense_1(v)
        rec = self.dense_2(rec)

        return v, rec


sub = subclass()
sub.model().summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28, 3)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 26, 26, 28)        784       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 13, 13, 28)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 tf.nn.relu (TFOpLambda)     (None, 13, 13, 28)        0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 13, 13, 512)       14848     
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 13, 13, 784)       402192    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 417,824
Trainable params: 417,824
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

However, what I would like to have is a call() architecture like the following:
(two tensor inputs at call([x,y]) )

```
import tensorflow as tf

class subclass(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(28, 3, strides=1)
        self.pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))

        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu')
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=784, activation='relu')

    def model(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
        y0 = tf.cast(tf.range(0, 10, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
        y = tf.keras.layers.Input(y0)
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x, y], outputs=self.call([x, y]))

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs

        # Match shapes for product
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=-1)
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=0)
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=0)

        # x = inputs
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[1] * x.shape[2], 10))
        x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
        v = tf.nn.relu(x)

        # Necessary operation for my reconstruction
        v_masked = tf.multiply(y, v)

        reconstruction = self.dense_1(v_masked)
        rec = self.dense_2(reconstruction)

        return v, rec

# %%
sub = subclass()
sub.model().summary()
```

When doing this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>' with type '<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>'
```

Similar approximations lead to the following error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index    
...    
TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by passing a `float` shape to `Input`?

Comment: I intend to pass the shape of the labels (let's say an original 1D vector that will become a 2D matrix with the batch size) to obtain the output shapes of each layer. For the simple case, by passing the layer.Input(input_shape=x.shape)), I'm able to call my model so I can get the output shapes. I intend to do something similar.